# Delegated Authentication Not Calling SSO Endpoint

Tags: delegated-authentication

I'm working on setting up delegated authentication for a Customer Community.  I've created the HTTP POST to the login page of the Community and am using the following URL for that:

https://SandboxName.pod.force.com/CommunityName/login

Based on my understanding, Salesforce should then call the SSO endpoint I have setup in the Delegated Gateway URL. However, in my testing this SSO endpoint is not getting called. I can tell this by the network traffic into the server where this is and the logging I have in the authenticate method. I've confirmed that the SSO endpoint is open and accessible outside of the firewall.

Any ideas what could be stopping this? I'm thinking I need to do something different with the login URL?

Comment: The endpoint is called when the user tries to log in. You're saying you're not seeing this happen? Their browser is *not* redirected to the endpoint upon trying to access the link or logging in.

Comment: Exactly, the browser is not redirected to the endpoint and the logging setup in the endpoint always indicates the user is not being redirected.

Comment: The browser *will not* be redirected, because *delegated authentication* means that salesforce.com calls the endpoint on your behalf and passes in the username and password that was supplied, and your endpoint returns either 'success' or 'failure'. At no point will your browser ever hit the endpoint or even know that it exists. Have you read [this help topic](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=sso_delauthentication_configuring.htm&language=en)? I think you're looking for regular SSO, which does redirect the browser to the endpoint for authentication.